# Contiguous memory allocation for 2D array --- freeing the memory

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am facing a heap crash during free() when I run this program, but I am successful if I do debug using F10 (in Visual studio 2010).

My piece of code:

The below code is used to free. Can someone please explain deallocation for 2D array in this case?

```
void Deallocate2D ( SINT32  **pAccess, UINT8 i_ubyNoOfRows )
{
    int i;
    UINT8 *elem;
    if ( NULL == pAccess )
    {
        printf ( "%d>Invalid Params\n", __LINE__ ); 
        return;
    }

    printf ( "\nDeallocate 2D Array..................\n" );

    /* Include the code to deallocate the 2D array */
    {   
            free(pAccess);  

    }
}
```

The below code is used for memory allocation:

```
SINT32 Allocate2D ( 
                SINT32  ***pAccess, 
                UINT8   i_ubyNoOfRows, 
                UINT8   i_ubyNoOfCols )
{
    SINT32  nResult = -1;
    SINT32  **pAc = NULL;
    UINT8   *pubyPositioner;
    UINT32  unTotalSize;
    int i;

    //unTotalSize = i_ubyNoOfRows * i_ubyNoOfCols;
    printf ( "\nAllocate 2D Array..................\n" );

    /* Include the code to allocate the 2D array */
    {

    /*Contiguous memallocation  pAc*/
    pAc = (SINT32**)malloc(sizeof(SINT32*) * i_ubyNoOfRows);
    if(pAc)
        pubyPositioner = (UINT8*)malloc(sizeof(UINT8) * i_ubyNoOfCols);
    if(pubyPositioner)
        for(i = 0; i < i_ubyNoOfCols; ++i)
            pAc[i] = (SINT32*)pubyPositioner + (i * i_ubyNoOfCols);             

    *pAccess = pAc;

    /*Non contugious allocation*/
    /*  
        pAc = (SINT32**)malloc(sizeof(SINT32*) * i_ubyNoOfRows );
        *pAccess = pAc;
        if(pAc)
         for(i= 0; i < i_ubyNoOfRows; ++i){
            pAc[i] = (SINT32*)malloc(sizeof(SINT32*) + (i * i_ubyNoOfRows) );
            if(pAc[i])
                for(j = 0; j < i_ubyNoOfCols; ++j)
                    pAc[i][j] = (UINT8)malloc(sizeof(UINT8) +   (i_ubyNoOfRows * i_ubyNoOfCols) );

         }

     */
        if(*pAccess != NULL)
            nResult = 0;


    }

    if ( NULL == pAccess )
    {
        printf ( "%d>Invalid Params\n", __LINE__ ); 
        return -1;
    }

    return nResult;
}
```

The code to fill array and print array:

```
SINT32 Fill2D ( 
                SINT32  **pnAccess,
                SINT32  *pnData,
                UINT8   i_ubyNoOfRows, 
                UINT8   i_ubyNoOfCols )
{
    SINT16  wRIndex, wCIndex, wDataIndex = 0;   



    printf ( "\nFill 2D Array..................\n" );

    /* Include the code to fill the 2D array with the 1D values */
    {
        for(wRIndex = 0 ; wRIndex < 3; ++wRIndex)
            for(wCIndex = 0; wCIndex < 3; ++wCIndex)
                pnAccess [wRIndex][wCIndex] = pnData[wDataIndex++];

    }

    if ( ( NULL == pnAccess ) \
            || ( NULL == pnData ) )
    {
        printf ( "%d>Invalid Params\n", __LINE__ ); 
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

SINT32 Print2D ( 
                SINT32  **pnAccess,
                UINT8   i_ubyNoOfRows, 
                UINT8   i_ubyNoOfCols )
{
    SINT16  wRIndex, wCIndex;

    if ( NULL == pnAccess )
    {
        printf ( "%d>Invalid Params\n", __LINE__ ); 
        return -1;
    }

    printf ( "\n2D Array..................\n\n" );

    /* Include the code to Print the 2D array in matrix format */
    {
        for(wRIndex = 0 ; wRIndex < i_ubyNoOfRows; ++wRIndex)
        {
            if(wRIndex % 2 == 0)
                printf("\n");
            for(wCIndex = 0; wCIndex < i_ubyNoOfCols; ++wCIndex)
                printf("%d ", pnAccess[wRIndex][wCIndex]); 

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The below code is kind of entry point:

```
void Test2DArray ( void )
{
    SINT32  **pnData = NULL;
    SINT32  nData1[] = { 10, 15, 20, 15, 20, 25, 10, 25, 20 };
    SINT32  nData2[] = { 70, 75, 80, 65, 90, 25, 30, 35, 80 };

    printf ( "\n==================================\n" );
    printf ( "Test 2D Array..................\n" );
    printf ( "==================================\n\n" );

    if ( Allocate2D( &pnData, 3, 3 ) != -1 )
    {
        if ( Fill2D( pnData, nData1, 3, 3 ) != - 1 )
        {
            if ( NULL != pnData )
            {
                Print2D ( pnData, 3, 3 );
                Deallocate2D ( pnData, 3 );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( Allocate2D( &pnData, 3, 3 ) != -1 )
    {
        if ( Fill2D( pnData, nData2, 3, 3 ) != - 1 )
        {
            if ( NULL != pnData )
            {
                Print2D ( pnData, 3, 3 );
                Deallocate2D ( pnData, 3 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't cast the pointer returned by `malloc`, and the rule of thumb is simple: every `malloc` call has to be paired with a `free` call. A 2D array can't be free'd in one go, but you'll have to free each pointer separatly: `char **foo; for (int i=0;i<foo_len;++i) free(foo[i]); free(foo);`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You are assuming that he is using a compliant C compiler to compile C code.

Comment: @lundin: No visual-C or C++ tags. If OP is using VC++ compiler, he should mention that

Comment: i am using MS Visual studio in which i am creating .c files to test the codes.Thanks for the response. please see that If i don't use cast the compiler shows error message in editor. @Lundin i had doubt about the contiguous allocation and pointer lookup table. I will study more on this

Answer (score 3):

```
 /*Contiguous memallocation  pAc*/
    pAc = (SINT32**)malloc(sizeof(SINT32*) * i_ubyNoOfRows);
    if(pAc)
        pubyPositioner = (UINT8*)malloc(sizeof(UINT8) * i_ubyNoOfCols);
    if(pubyPositioner)
        for(i = 0; i < i_ubyNoOfCols; ++i)
            pAc[i] = (SINT32*)pubyPositioner + (i * i_ubyNoOfCols);
```

This is not contiguous memory allocation! It is a pointer-based lookup table which is allocated in one segment, pointing at a chunk of memory allocated in another segment.

Correct code for allocating a true 2D array would be:

```
SINT32 (*pAc)[ubyNoOfCols] = malloc( sizeof(SINT32[i_ubyNoOfCols][i_ubyNoOfRows]) );
...
free(pAc);
```

Note that this will only compile on a C compiler, so you can't use Visual Studio.

---

> Can someone please explain deallocation for 2D array in this case?

```
free(pAccess);
```

Looks like the code only deallocates the pointer lookup table and not the actual data. So I suppose that is a bug: the code contains memory leaks.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oops, indeed there were some copy/paste errors. Thanks for pointing that out, fixed. `pAc` in the original code, is declared to a pointer-to-pointer, which is not the same thing as a pointer to array. Whether to use cols or rows as the first dimension depends on the nature of the application, there's no telling if it is based on "(x, y)" mathematical coordinates or something else.

Comment: Still, the core problems here are: the memory is not allocated adjacently, and there seems to be a memory leak in the deallocation.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at your allocation code:

```
pAc = (SINT32**)malloc(sizeof(SINT32*) * i_ubyNoOfRows);
if(pAc)
    pubyPositioner = (UINT8*)malloc(sizeof(UINT8) * i_ubyNoOfCols);
if(pubyPositioner)
    for(i = 0; i < i_ubyNoOfCols; ++i)
        pAc[i] = (SINT32*)pubyPositioner + (i * i_ubyNoOfCols);
```

So, you are first allocating memory for `i_ubyNoOfRows` pointers. This is fine.
Then you proceed to allocate `i_ubyNoOfCols` **bytes**, (3 bytes in your test case), but you need space for `i_ubyNoOfCols*i_ubyNoOfRows` **integers** (3*3*4 = 36 bytes in your test case, assuming `int` is a 32-bit type).
When you proceed to initialize your memory, you trod on data vital for `malloc()` and `free()` to function properly.

A telltale sign of one half of your mistake is the cast in the line `pAc[i] = (SINT32*)pubyPositioner + (i * i_ubyNoOfCols);`. It shows that you used a wrong type for `pubyPostitioner`.

Ps: You have two `3`s hardcoded in `Fill2D()`, even though this function gets the correct width and height passed as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> In my question,I wanted to allocate memory for 2D array then free it.
>   After some study, i have explained my understanding as below
>
> 1. Allocate memory using array of pointers

```
double **p;
int i;
p= malloc(rows * sizeof(*p));
for(i= 0; i<rows;++i)
p[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));
```

...
 ...

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    free(p[i]);
 free(p);
```

> 1. allocation using pointer lookup table

```
double **p;
double *elem;

elem = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(double));
p = malloc(cols * sizeof(double*));
for (i = 0; i<rows;++i)
p[i] =  elem + ( i*cols);

free(p);
```

> 1. Contiguous Allocation

```
double **p;
p = malloc( rows * cols * sizeof(double*));
/*Accessing / printing values ... assume values are assinged to this array*/
for(i=0; i <rows; ++i)
 for(j = 0; j< cols; ++j)
  printf("%d",p[j + (i * cols)]);

free(p)
```